# PHP - Return array to jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following function that runs whenever my form gets submitted `(post.php)`:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'prize.php',
                cache: false,
                dataType:'json',
                beforeSend: function(req) {
                    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8');
                },
                data: { stime: stime, key: key, aa: vAd , sw: screen.width, sh: screen.height, saw:screen.availWidth, sah: screen.availHeight, scd: screen.colorDepth, tz: (new Date().getTimezoneOffset()), bp: sbp, hf: have_flash},
                success: function(data){
                if(data.data == 'success'){
                    console.log(data.text);
                }else {
                  alert("error");
                 }


                },
                error: function (){
                }
                });
```

The `prize.php` looks like this:

```
if($_POST)
{
    $validate = $wheel->validate();

    $error = '';
    $stop = false;

    switch($validate)
    {
            case 1:
                $error = 'You\'re not logged in..';
                $stop = true;
            break;
    }

        //If no error = success.    
        if($validate['code'] == "100"){
            $won = $validate['prize'];
            $type = $validate['type'];
            $data = array("data"=>"success","code"=>"100","prize"=>"$prize","type"=>"$type");
            echo json_encode($data);
            die();
        }

        die($error);

}
```

Now, the `wheel.php (validate() function)` will return this:

```
$text = "dollar";
$prize = "50";
return array("data"=>"success","code"=>"100","prize"=>"$prize","type"=>"$text");
```

My problem is that I cannot use the "`prize`" nor the "`type`" from the array above, when I:

```
console.log(data.prize);
```

it returns "undefined".

Although if I do the same with: `console.log(data.code);` it returns `100`

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the values from the array where the values are variables and not hardcoded?

Comment: He didn't use `return`

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are parsing the response?? Try `JSON.parse` on the returned data before `console.log`

Comment: @taylorcressy, since OP is using jQuery's ajax method with an option of `dataType` set to `json` it will automatically parse JSON text to javascript object

Comment: is `$won = $validate['prize'];` supposed to be `$prize` -> `"prize"=>"$prize"`?

Comment: @taylorcressy I am.. I've set the dataType to json..

Comment: @Sean the array "prize" should simply return the content of "$prize"

Comment: Ah right, I never use this syntax ha. I prefer $.post / $.get

Comment: but where are you defining `$prize` in `prize.php`. I only see `$won`, which is equal to `$validate['prize']`?

Comment: Yeah, don't think the variable exists. lol (or is out of scope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$prize` variable apperently does not exist change it to `$won`

```
if($_POST)
{
    $validate = $wheel->validate();

    $error = '';
    $stop = false;

    switch($validate)
    {
            case 1:
                $error = 'You\'re not logged in..';
                $stop = true;
            break;
    }

        //If no error = success.    
        if($validate['code'] == "100"){
            $won = $validate['prize'];
            $type = $validate['type'];
            $data = array("data"=>"success","code"=>"100","prize"=>"$won","type"=>"$type"); // $prize to $won
            echo json_encode($data);
            die();
        }

        die($error);

}
```

Comment: It returns: "undefined".. As said in the OP

Comment: @oliverbj Where does it say that in the OP? Isaac is talking about the PHP, not the JavaScript.

Comment: @showdev Sorry for the misunderstanding I edited my answer since that's why oliverbj is speaking about OP :/

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't notice that the answer had been edited.